# AFNetworking Cause Error while using XCTest in Xcode5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, xctest

I am using Xcode 5 and now just started unit testing on my existing project, for that I added the `CocoaTouch Unit Testing Bundle` as a target (Target Name is : MyAppTests) to my project.I was previously added AFNetworking library using `CocoaPods`,while I am running the test Case I got the error AFNetworking.h file not found.
 I added AFNetworking.h in the Tests.m but issue till remains. Is there any additional setting s for including the Pods to my testing target??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Got the solution finally.
select `info` of the project then select `Configuration` select the dropdown `Debug`. From that list select your test target and change the None in `Configurations Set` Tab into Pods.
 Do the same in `Release` Tab also

Answer (score 0):

CocoaPods's wiki: [multiple-targets](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html) may give you some advices.

Change your podfile ,and run "pod install" again!