# How to use cocoapods in an exist ios project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have an ios project first made in Xcode4.6. I have update it to Xcode5.0.2. Now I want to change the project to using **cocoapods** to manage the third party pods.

Due to a newer to cocoapods.I search the Internet to how to install cocoapods and so on.Now it's OK.So I run the pod install to get "AFFnetworking 2.1.0". .xcworkspace generate successfully.Then I open the workspace.I saw this in the navigation

[image]

There are many question mark.I think this means that Xcode5.0.2 didn't know the AFNetworking 2.1.0 added by cocoapods. And If I write the `"#import "AFNetworking.h"` in a .m file. Xcode will say that can't find the `"AFNetworking.h"`.

I am a newer to cocoapods. So home someone could help me. Tanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question marks are coming from your version-control system, not from Xcode itself; they indicate that the files added by CocoaPods are new to version control. I’d recommend committing all of the CocoaPods-related files right away so that you have just one commit that represents “moving to CocoaPods”.

Answer (score 2):

Because AFNetworking is linked as a library you need to use the `< >` import style. So `#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using git repository.Add files pod to repository, currently they are untracked thats the reason for '?' there.if the error persists then see the following discussion

[AFNetworking Cause Error while using XCTest in Xcode5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994720/afnetworking-cause-error-while-using-xctest-in-xcode5/20063477#20063477)